# Read Observable array data in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new user for angular and firebase. I used to AngularFireDatabase to get data from firebase real time database. I need to read last updated data in database. I used below code to read it.

```
items: Observable<any[]>;
 
constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase) {
 
  this.items = db.list('DistanceVariationForDiffUserMockDataInfo', ref => ref.orderByChild("distance").limitToLast(1)).valueChanges();

}
```

My database structure [image]

I need to assign distance variable from database to another variable in my code. How to do it. Please give me a support to do that.

I need to get below output by using distance value. it's distance value is 5. I need to get that distance from my database.
[image]

[image]

I already found the minimum and maximum distance to cells from point 0. I require to color the relevant cells when selecting a distance. Distance taken from firebase database.

```
cells= [
{ id: 1, minDistance: 0.0, maxDistance: 1.4142135623730951 },
{ id: 2, minDistance: 1.0, maxDistance: 2.23606797749979 },
{ id: 3, minDistance: 2.0, maxDistance: 3.1622776601683795 },
{ id: 4, minDistance: 3.0, maxDistance: 4.123105625617661 },
{ id: 5, minDistance: 4.0, maxDistance: 5.0990195135927845 },
{ id: 6, minDistance: 5.0, maxDistance: 6.082762530298219 },
{ id: 7, minDistance: 6.0, maxDistance: 7.0710678118654755 },
{ id: 8, minDistance: 7.0, maxDistance: 8.06225774829855 },
{ id: 9, minDistance: 8.0, maxDistance: 9.055385138137417 },
{ id: 10, minDistance: 9.0, maxDistance: 10.04987562112089 },
```

Some cells in my code.

```
getCellColor(cell){
if (this.distance >= cell.minDistance && this.distance <= cell.maxDistance && this.distance > 0 ) {
  return "red";
} else{
  return "green";
}
```

}

Used to filter cells after giving distance.

Comment: Please explain more about your use case. Why do you only want this single field? Is it to perform an operation on it? Is it to display it to the screen? In both of those scenarios there are methods to work directly with the observable

Comment: I need to color grid cells by using distance value. I added picture.

Comment: So you need to get the distance of each node (grid on your screen) and change the grid element's styles? Why not use ngClass or ngStyle to apply styles directly from the HTML template instead of creating a secondary array to store all this information? If you're able to provide a more complete example of your use case then I can better help solve your problem

Comment: Hi @Hydra, Can you help me to complete my task.

Comment: Please add more examples of your code so I can see the full picture